# How do we get the words that we typed previously when we type that 1st letter of the word

Tags: asp.net

I am very new to .net. I was wondering How do we get the words that we typed 
previously when we type that 1st letter of the word in Textbox

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on where you typed previously and what you did with that data. Where are the "words", (i.e strings) stored?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking for is a ***browser property***. For most of the browsers auto complete feature will be turned on by default.

All the other answers will get you auto complete texts that are stored in a location(DB or somewhere else) and not your previously typed values.